# Can I mix shifter (deore m4100 10 speed) with my Rear Derailleur (deore m6000)?

Tags: shifter, derailleur-rear, compatibility

Can I use deore m4100 10speed shifter with my RD deore m6000 10speed RD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all Shimano mountain 10 is the same actuation rate for rear derailleurs as can be seen in the [compatibility chart](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com?cid=C-432&acid=C-436):
[image]

Note that 9, 11, and 12 are all different, so speed generation mismatches are the thing that doesn't work.

Comment: This may be best asked in a separate question, but how do the RD-M4120 & RD-M5120 work for both 10 and 11 speed as listed on the Shimano spec page?  Ten and 11s are close enough to the same actuation ratio to work?